# Cant access property inside map function with spring transitions in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error

I am new in React and in React Spring. What I try to do is do some fade in and out effects with useTranstion. I have divs with texts and images and both will have different transitions, but for testing purposes are both same now. My inspiration is from React Spring examples, here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/morr206pv8.

But whatever I try to do, I still getting errors with `TypeError: can't access property "text", item is undefined` from map function. Same happens with images.

And one more error is this: [image] and I have no idea what it is.

Can someone please help me and explain what I did wrong? I will be very thankful.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTransition, animated } from 'react-spring';

import Slide1 from "../images/slide1.jpg";
import Slide2 from "../images/slide2.jpg";
import Slide3 from "../images/slide3.jpg";

const Slider = () =>{

  const texts = [
    {id: 0, text: "Text1"},
    {id: 1, text: "Text2"},
    {id: 2, text: "Text3"},
  ];

  const images = [
    { id: 0, image: Slide1 },
    { id: 1, image: Slide2 },
    { id: 2, image: Slide3 },
  ];

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const textTransitions = useTransition(texts[index], item => item.id, {
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
  });

  const imageTransitions = useTransition(images[index], item => item.id, {
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
  });

  useEffect(() => void setInterval(() => setIndex(state => (state + 1) % 3), 2500), []);

  return(
    <div className="sliderContainer">

      {textTransitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
        <animated.div className="sliderText" style={props} key={key} >
          <h1><span></span>Autorizovaný chiptuning</h1>
          <p>{item.text}</p>
        </animated.div>
      ))}

      <div className="sliderImage">
        {imageTransitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
            <animated.img src={item.image} key={key} style={props} alt="" />
        ))}
      </div>

    </div>
  );

}

export default Slider;
```

Here is full error:
[image]

### EDIT #1

So answer is that this syntax of `useTransition` dont work in versions 9 and up. If you want to work with this syntax, use for example version 8.0.27. Hope it will help someone with same problem.

### EDIT #2

If you want to write this in version 9 or higher, write it like this or change it for your own purpose.

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => void setInterval(() => setIndex((state) => (state + 1) % 3), 4000), []);

const texts = [
    {id: 0, text: "Chiptuning osobních aut"},
    {id: 1, text: "Chiptuning nákladních aut"},
    {id: 2, text: "Chiptuning zemědělské techniky"},
  ];

const textTransitions = useTransition(texts[index], {
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: "translate3d(0,-15%,0) scale3d(1,1.1,1)" },
    enter: { opacity: 1, transform: "translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1)" },
    leave: { opacity: 0, transform: "translate3d(0,15%,0) scale3d(1,0.95,1)" },
    config: config.gentle,
    key: texts[index].id,
  });

return(

 {textTransitions((props, item) => (
      <animated.div className="sliderText" style={props}>
        <h1>
          <span>A</span>utorizovaný chiptuning QUANTUM
        </h1>
        <p>{item.text}</p>
      </animated.div>
   ))}

);
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. If you fork the sandbox you linked and replace their code with your text transition code it works fine.

Comment: The sandbox does same error as my code.. Can it cause different version of React Spring?

Comment: Yes, @Kretiss. `react-spring` version 8.0.5 is working fine. But latest version is not.

Comment: Here is a [working fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/usetransition-demo-fork-6hv3o?file=/src/index.js) with your code. It's working with the latest version of v8. v9 has a completely different API for useTransition so it would throw an error before getting to `item.text` anyway.

Comment: @lawrence-witt thank you very much. I mooved down to 8.0.27 version and it works fine. Anyway, dont you know about good source of React Spring tutorials?

Comment: The [docs](https://www.react-spring.io/) are the only place that I know of that covers the API in any detail (not very well to be honest). If you found that example you probably know about it already. I basically learned it by reading them, playing with the examples, and searching github issues when I got stuck.